# jboss intellij https management interface not supported, please disable it and use http management interface instead

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, web-applications, jboss

I am building a spring boot application in IntelliJ idea and Trying to Deploy it in JBoss. When I create a new JBoss configuration for the application I get this warning in the bottom saying

Connection to HTTPS management interface not supported yet. Please disable it and use HTTP management interface instead.

I am using JBoss EAP 6.2.0 and IntelliJ 2018 with latest spring boot dependencies. My configuration starts but dosent connect to the server and when i do netstat on cmd i see that the ports that the server should be listening on dont have anything listening on them.

Can someone tell me how to solve this warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss integration doesn't yep support https connection to Management Interface. Related request: [IDEA-144621](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144621).

As a workaround, you can change your standalone.xml to switch to http admin:

```
<management-interfaces>
...
    <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm" http-upgrade-enabled="true">
        <socket-binding http="management-http"/> <!-- '-http' instead of '-https' here -->
    </http-interface>
</management-interfaces>
```

Comment: do u know how to do this using the management console as editing the XML is not recommended